# AngularJS + SailsJS : Body parameters missing in a multipart post request irregularly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am developing an [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) app with a [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) backend. In my [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) app, I am uploading a file using multipart upload with parameters as shown below.

```
function upload(url, params, callback) {

    var fd = new FormData();

    _.map(params, function(value, key) {
        fd.append(key, value);
    });

    $http.post(url + '?q=' + new Date().getTime(), fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            callback(response);
        })
        .error(function(response) {
            callback(response);
        });
}
```

In my [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) app, I receive the request as follows

```
var params = req.body;
params.file = req.file('file');
```

I am able to receive the file consistantly. But the parameters within `req.body` seems to be missing in some requests even though it is being send from the `angular` app.

Any thoughts?